# Change innerHTML in electron window

Tags: javascript, html, electron

A pretty basic electron question, explaining it by a specific example:

in my first electron app I want to change the innerHTML of a label **before** sync-copying a larger file.

here's what I wrongfully thought the solution is. with this code, the label text is changed **after** the file was copied:

renderer.js:

```
const lbl = document.getElementById('statusLabel')
lbl.innerHTML = "New Description"
fs.copyFileSync(...)
```

However, I can "force" first updating the label by this:

renderer.js:

```
const lbl = document.getElementById('statusLabel')
lbl.innerHTML = "New Description"
ipcRenderer.send('copyFile')
```

main.js:

```
ipcMain.on('copyFile', () => {
    ipcMain.send('copyFile'))
}
```

I could replace fs.copyFileSync with any other function - the point is, I only get it to work in the required order by sending the subsequent action to the renderer.

is this intended electron behaviour or did I miss something basic?

Comment: You should not need to send an IPC message just to dynamically change the inner text of a page element. It looks like a timing issue between updating the element and performing the `fs` command. Perhaps the `fs` command blocks the (apparent) update of the render until the `fs` operation is complete. After all, it is a synchronous operation. Do you have `nodeIntegration` set to `true`? The reason I ask is because you are using Node's `fs.copyFileSync(...)` directly within your render. Perhaps this operation should be performed in your main thread instead?